# Restoring a SQL Server Express Edition Database

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to take a backup file from SQL Server Express Edition and restore it into a standard SQL Server database?  I tried to do it from Management Studio but it didn't recognize the file format.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a databse .bak file you can move from SQL Server 2005 Express to SQL Server.

Just make sure that you check the option to overwrite the existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It should work using the standard tools.  What versions of the databases are you working with?

Comment: I think I know why I encountered a problem.  I'm using SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, but the standard version of SQL Server that I tried to import into is SQL Server 2000.